# Calculating parent value based on children values

Tags: elixir, comparison

Apologies if the title doesn't make sense, I'm struggling to describe what it is precisely but hopefully, the following will enlighten you.

This is part of an AoC challenge but I believe it's a specific enough question that one might run into it anyway. For the challenge, I don't think I'm going at it the right way, building a tree would be better but now I just want to know how to solve this issue.

---

### Where I'm at

My data looks like the following:

```
iex(249)> Day7.part1
[
  %{path: ["/", "a", "e"], size: 584},
  %{path: ["/", "a"], size: 94269},
  %{path: ["/", "d"], size: 24933642},
  %{path: ["/"], size: 23352670}
]
```

What I want to do is iterate through where I compare the `:path` values, if they match then the shorter list must be the parent and the parent `:size` will be updated such that `size: parent.size + child.size`. Or something like that at least.

---

### Desired output

```
iex(249)> Day7.part1
[
  %{path: ["/", "a", "e"], size: 584},
  %{path: ["/", "a"], size: 94853},
  %{path: ["/", "d"], size: 24933642},
  %{path: ["/"], size: 48381165}
]
```

---

### What I've attempted so far

```
  def child_dirs([], system), do: system
  def child_dirs([head | tail] = dirs, system) do
      Enum.map(dirs, fn x ->
        if x.path == List.delete_at(head.path, -1) do
          system = system ++ [%{path: x.path, size: head.size + x.size}]
        end
      end)
      child_dirs(tail, system)
  end
```

Which results in the following

```
iex(281)> Day7.part1 |> Day7.child_dirs([])
[]
```

But if I change `system = system ++ ...` to inspect it, like so `IO.inspect(system = system ++ [%{path: x.path, size: head.size + x.size}])`. I get the following:

```
iex(284)> Day7.part1 |> Day7.child_dirs([])
[%{path: ["/", "a"], size: 94853}]
[%{path: ["/"], size: 23446939}]
[%{path: ["/"], size: 48286312}]
[]
```

So it's clearly working in some regard but just not adding the updated values to the ongoing *accumulator* named `system`.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated :)

Comment: _Sidenote:_ your solution fails because `system = …` line does not update the topmost `system` variable, it rebinds the local one inside `if/2` scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s most likely not the optimal way, but it’s the most clean and idiomatic one, AFACT.

```elixir
input
[
  %{path: ["/", "a", "e"], size: 584},
  %{path: ["/", "a"], size: 94269},
  %{path: ["/", "d"], size: 24933642},
  %{path: ["/"], size: 23352670}
]
```

Walk through the list, select from this list elements which start with the current one, and sum them all.

```elixir
for %{path: path} <- input do
  size =
    input
    |> Enum.filter(&Enum.slice(&1.path, 0..length(path)-1) == path)
    |> Enum.map(& &1.size)
    |> Enum.sum()
  %{path: path, size: size}
end
#⇒ [
#   %{path: ["/", "a", "e"], size: 584},
#   %{path: ["/", "a"], size: 94853},
#   %{path: ["/", "d"], size: 24933642},
#   %{path: ["/"], size: 48381165}
# ]
```